# Django Authentication Backend

Tags: django, django-authentication

How i know in server-side what authentication backend is for determinated user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After authenticating, each User object will have a 'backend' property, pointing to the module and class that authenticated him. You can see related code [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L57).